# Cannot Disable Extension

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, supee-6788, supee-7405

So I have a couple of "Custom" manually installed extension (installed without using MAGENTO Installed)
When I go to Advanced tab and click "Disable", these extension still execute their normal functions. Basically continue working as it is.
**System > Configuration > Advanced**

For me to completely disable extension I have to go to "etc" folder and change "True" to "False"

Do you think the reason I cannot disable  extensions form back-end admin panel is due to recent SUPEE patch updates?

Comment: this is the correct way to disable extension - got to `app/etc/modules/` and rename extension `.xml` to `.xml_off`

Answer (score 2):

No, it's because that is how Magento extensions are created.  It doesn't have anything to do with the SUPEE patch.

If you look closely at the **System -> Configuration -> Advanced ->Advanced** section, you will see the group is actually called *"Disable Modules Output"*.  This setting does not actually disable your module.  It only disables block output for your module.

If you want to disable your module, go inside of *app/etc/modules/* and change the `<active>` flag from `true` to `false`, (like you mentioned).

**NOTE:** Even though it is disabled, it will still show up in the "Disabled Modules Output" screen.

Comment: Many Thanks Ryan! That's what I also thought. Wanted confirmation from others. Cheers!

Comment: glad to help :)